# Chaning turn signal flasher in a 1996 Buick Century

Tags: electrical, buick, century, flasher

I need to know how many flashers a 1996 Buick Century has and how to change a flasher?

Comment: Please provide some background to your question, such as what problem you are trying to resolve and what you have attempted or researched so far.